# Finding rows of certain conditions after rows of other conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, count

To gauge the effectiveness of giving free product in getting new customers, I want to find the number of customers who have paid for an order after only receiving a free order. My table looks like:

```
id | user | total
-----------------
 1    1     0.00
 2    1     57.33
 3    2     58.21
 4    2     0.00
 5    3     26.10
 6    3     0.00
 7    3     64.94
 8    4     0.00
 9    5     34.54
```

In this table there's five customers: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`. This counts for all of the conditions I can think of.

- User 1 received a free order and then placed a paid order, this counts
- User 2 placed a paid order and then received a free order, this does not count
- User 3 placed a paid order, then received a free order, then placed a paid order, this does not count
- User 4 received a free order, this does not count
- User 5 placed a paid order, this does not count

You can see I only care about users who have not placed a paid order before receiving a free order, and then placed a paid order. A more declarative definition of the count I'm looking for is:

- Users placed an order `n` where `n->total > 0` after receiving an order `m`, where `m->total == 0` and `m->id < n->id`. There is no order `w` where `w->total > 0` and `w->id < m->id`.

Some `create table` code:

```
create table orders (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user int,
    total decimal(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

insert into orders (user, total) values
    (1, 0.00),
    (1, 57.33),
    (2, 58.21),
    (2, 0.00),
    (3, 26.10),
    (3, 0.00),
    (3, 64.94),
    (4, 0.00),
    (5, 34.54);
```

The expected output in this case would be `1`.

Comment: is this line correct? **You can see I only care about users who have not placed a paid order before receiving a paid order,**

Comment: To address your logic, I believe we would need to look at the three most recent ID values for each user and the corresponding timestamps.  This is a bit tricky in MySQL, and I think the answer might require some dynamic SQL.

Comment: @1000111 sorry, made a typo there. I've fixed it, it should have been "who have not placed a paid order before receiving a free order".

Comment: Which column makes the sequence of orders?  Is it the ID or do you have a timestamp column not shown here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple aggregation combined with conditional aggregation gets you the user you are looking for.

```
SELECT
    [user]
    ,MIN(id) as MinId
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN id END) as MinZeroId
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN total > 0 THEN id END) as MinPositiveId
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY
    [user]
HAVING
    MIN(id) = MIN(CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN id END)
    AND MIN(CASE WHEN total > 0 THEN id END) > MIN(CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN id END)
```

That compares the minimum id for the user against the minimum id for $0 total and then compares the minimum id for a Total > $0 to the minimum id for $0 Total.

And if you want the original records simply add an outer select to get to it.

```
SELECT o.*
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          [user]
       FROM
          orders
       GROUP BY
          [user]
       HAVING
          MIN(id) = MIN(CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN id END)
          AND MIN(CASE WHEN total > 0 THEN id END) > MIN(CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN id END)
    ) t
    INNER JOIN orders o
    ON t.[user] = o.[user]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the pairs of records (self join) where the first record (the where clause) has a zero total and there exists a subsequent record with a non-zero total. (doesn't have to be the next record, right?)

```
Select i.User, i.total firstTotal, 
    n.Total firstpaidTotal 
from table i
  join table n
     on n.Id > i.id
         and n.user = i.user
         and n.total > 0
where i.total = 0
  and not exists 
   (Select * from table
    where user = i.user
       and id < i.Id)
```

Comment: Not exactly because of user 3 in his example. If 0.00 then >0.00 then 0.00 it should be excluded, which would not be the case with your query. Nice beginning anyway :-)

Comment: The not exists would exclude user 3.it only allows records where the id is the lowest for that user and the total = 0

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your question:

```
select a.id from orders a
join orders b on (a.user = b.user and a.id < b.id and a.total = 0)
join (select min(id) as id, user from orders group by user) c on (a.user = c.user and a.id = c.id)
```

Let me know if anything is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible solution, though I personally like @Matt answer over this one:

```
SELECT a.user
FROM orders a
  -- search first user_line
  JOIN (
      SELECT b.user, MIN(b.id) first_id
      FROM orders b
      GROUP BY b.user
    ) c ON a.user = c.user AND a.id = c.first_id
WHERE
  -- check first line is total=0
  a.total = 0
  -- has later lines with total>0
  AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 'exists'
      FROM orders c
      WHERE 
        c.user = a.user 
        AND c.total > 0
        AND c.id > a.id
    )
```